# 特定の文字に色を付ける方法

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、誕生日が来るとアナログ時計の外周に"メッセージ”が表示され、
誕生日が過ぎると次の誕生日まで"カレンダー"が表示されます。
このメッセージの中に表示される年齢(～歳)だけに『赤色』にするということは、可能でしょうか。
可能でしたら、ご教示ください。

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }

    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}


var dCol = '00ff00', //date colour.
    sCol = 'ff0000', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '000000', //minutes colour.
    hCol ='000000', //hours colour.
    fCol = '0000ff', //face color
    ClockHeight = 40,
    ClockWidth = 40,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,

 birthday = new Date(1917, 2, 12);

           if ((new Date().getMonth() == birthday.getMonth()) && (new Date().getDate() == birthday.getDate())) {
                var age = new Date().getYear()- birthday.getYear();
       var  TodaysDate="金さん銀さん"+" "+age+"歳の誕生日"+" "+"おめでとう"+" ";
}else{
var d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
}

var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '...';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '....';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '.....';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.6;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.06,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];

var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}

var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';


// Date wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Hours wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Minute wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Seconds wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Mouse move event handler
function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }


}
document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

とりあえず誕生日の場合は以下の様なDOMが形成されています。

```
<div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 323.002px; left: 536.566px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">金</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 311.003px; left: 549.829px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">さ</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 303.447px; left: 566.04px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">ん</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 301.005px; left: 583.757px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">銀</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 303.893px; left: 601.408px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">さ</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 311.856px; left: 617.422px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">ん</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 324.186px; left: 630.378px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">1</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 339.786px; left: 639.125px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">0</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 357.272px; left: 642.884px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">0</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 375.088px; left: 641.323px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">歳</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 391.653px; left: 634.579px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">の</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 405.495px; left: 623.252px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">誕</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 415.382px; left: 608.349px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">生</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 420.438px; left: 591.193px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">日</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 420.212px; left: 573.309px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00"> </span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 414.725px; left: 556.287px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">お</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 404.465px; left: 541.638px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">め</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 390.342px; left: 530.664px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">で</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 373.612px; left: 524.34px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">と</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 355.761px; left: 523.229px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00">う</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 338.376px; left: 527.429px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#00ff00"> </span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

これらの中の年齢(～歳)の部分だけ色を赤に変えれば(color:#ff0000)良いです。

```
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 324.186px; left: 630.378px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#ff0000">1</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 339.786px; left: 639.125px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#ff0000">0</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 357.272px; left: 642.884px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#ff0000">0</span></div>
        <div class="Date" name="Date" style="position: absolute; top: 375.088px; left: 641.323px; height: 10px; width: 10px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:1em; color:#ff0000">歳</span></div>
```

名前の部分(金さん銀さん)が固定であれば強引に７文字目以降から"歳"の文字までの色を変えるといったコードを考えつきましたが、年齢(～歳)を表示したい箇所の細かい仕様がわからないので、考え方だけ記載します。
名前の部分が可変になると、全体的に見直す必要があり、現状のコードではかなり厳しいと思います。

---

追記：かなり強引なコードなのであまりお勧めしたくありませんが、

```
birthday = new Date(1917, 2, 12);
var isBirthDay = false;

if ((new Date().getMonth() == birthday.getMonth()) && (new Date().getDate() == birthday.getDate())) {
    var age = new Date().getYear()- birthday.getYear();
    var  TodaysDate="金さん銀さん"+" "+age+"歳の誕生日"+" "+"おめでとう"+" ";
    isBirthDay = true;
}else{

(略)

// Date wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

if (isBirthDay) {
    var divChildren = $('Od').children[0].children;
    for (i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++) {
        var divEl = divChildren[i];
        if (i >= 6) {
            divEl.children[0].style.color = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
            if (divEl.textContent === "歳") {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 詳しい回答をありがとうございました。細かなところはまだ分かりませんが、希望通りに表示されました

Comment: それでしたら、"if(birthday)~else"の中にある"Sunday(＊曜日は任意でいいです)"も色を付けられるはずですが、組み立てうまくいきません。お手数ですが、書き方を教えていただけませんでしょうか。色は、"赤色"でお願いします。

Comment: 失礼ですが質問の量のコードが書ける方であれば少し変えるだけで希望されている対応もできるように思えます。回答で示したコードは`isBirthDay`の変数と`if (isBirthDay)`で括られた部分しか追加していません。`divChildren`は「DOMがこのように形成されています〜」で示した`<div class="Date"〜`の要素の配列です。`divEl.children[0]`がさらにその中の`<span>`要素にあたります。さらにstyle.colorで色の指定を変更しています。少しずつデバッグしていけばどんな要素があって、どの値を何に変えているのかは確認できます。また、「組み立ててうまくいきません。」では何がわかっていてどこでつまづいているのかがわかりません。試されたこと、どこまでできたのかなどを質問に加えるようにしてください。

Comment: 少しずつデバッグして‌​行けば希望通りに色は付くのですが、配列ではなくて数で色が付くので、TodaysDate="~"の中の順番は変えられないようですね

Comment: TodaysDateは1文字分解されて、それぞれDOM要素になっています。もう一度回答にある「以下の様なDOMが形成されています。」の部分をよく見てください。`配列ではなくて数で色が付くので、TodaysDate="~"の‌​中の順番は変えられないようですね`が何を言っているのかよくわかりませんが、曜日が表示される場合は`Sunday `のようになっていると思います。`isBirthDay`が`false`の場合に、`TodaysDate`の1つ目の半角スペースから2つ目の半角スペースの間の色を変えることで対応できました。色を変える箇所の開始条件と終了条件を決めるだけです。

Comment: 何度も試してみて気づいたのですが、"Od(年･月日・曜日)"のうち、d(Sunday～Saturday)の全体が赤色が付いてしまいます。"Sunday"のみに色を付けるのに手間取っています。